# In rust concatenating bytes, strings and comparison

Tags: rust

I have the following code snippet for `CR` and `LF` comparison. It compiles and runs, but it seems like an odd syntax to be using. I was wondering if there is more natural way of making the comparison without casting both the left and right hand sides.

```
pub const CR: u8 = b'\r';
pub const LF: u8 = b'\n';
pub const CRLF: [u8, ..2] = [CR,LF]; // this probably should have a different type?

let mut cur_line: String;
// *snip getting line value*

// casting both the left and right hand side, is there a better way?
if cur_line.as_bytes() == &CRLF {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d use `&'static [u8]`:

```
pub const CRLF: &'static [u8] = b"\r\n";  // or &[CR, LF]
```

I would also say that you should be careful about the line types that you’re using; is `cur_line` guaranteed to be UTF-8? If not, it should be `Vec<u8>` rather than `String`, and `CRLF` should potentially be `&'static str`, `"\r\n"`. But anyway, the comparison `cur_line.as_bytes() == CRLF` is fine. (Once it’s `&'static [u8]` rather than `[u8, ..2]`, the `&` isn’t needed.)

Comment: Thank you. I am getting my line from `BufferedStream<TcpStream>::read_line()` when i read my lines elsewhere, i use `&str::read_line()`.